VBA Macro Question Not going into specific macro line of Code
Below is my Data set. What it supposed to do is keep track of the Level and if Operational FR User Set? is "True" and the level below it is greater than the previous level delete Entire row of Level 2. My macro works about but does not go into the delete part of the macro to delete entire row. Can some please explain what i am doing incorrectly?

Macro is below.
Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String, wks As Worksheet) As Integer
Dim headers As Range

Set headers = wks.Range("A1:AX1")
GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function


Public Sub StripBomFields_Description_PartNumber()

Dim stripStrings As Variant

'stripStrings = Range("Remove_Part_Strings").Value
    
    
Dim fieldToSearch(1) As String
fieldToSearch(0) = "Operational FR User Set?"
'fieldToSearch(1) = "Environment"
'fieldToSearch(2) = "Part Number"

'Dim wb As Workbook
'Set wb = Workbooks.Open(get_user_specified_filepath(), ReadOnly:=False)

'Assume first sheet
'Dim wks As Worksheet

'Set wks = wb.Sheets(1)

    
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim sField As String
Dim rowCount As Integer
rowCount = 1
Dim bToDelete As Boolean
Dim iPriorLevel As Integer
iPriorLevel = 1
iUserSetLevel = 0
bToDelete = False
Dim Environment As String
Environment = ""
Dim SetEnv As Boolean
SetEnv = False
For Each bomField In fieldToSearch
    Dim DeleteRng As Range
    Set DeleteRng = Nothing
    sField = bomField
    'Locate the used cells in the column whose header row is the fieldToSearch
    Set InputRng = Range(Cells(2, 31), Cells(2, 31).End(xlDown))
       'For Each stripString In stripStrings
        For Each Rng In InputRng
            'Get current part row Level
            curLevel = Cells(Rng.Row, 7).Value
              'If (bToDelete) Then 'Our last rng was a delete rng
              '  bToDelete = curLevel > iUserSetLevel 'We are below the level of higher delete part?
            'End If
            'If (InStr(1, Rng.Text, stripString, vbTextCompare) > 0) Or (bToDelete) Then
             If (InStr(1, Rng.Text, "TRUE", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                'We are in delete mode
                ' Get the current delete level
                'If (Not bToDelete) Then
                    iUserSetLevel = curLevel
                    bToDelete = True
            End If
            'This is looking at the Environment Column
            If (Not IsEmpty(Cells(Rng.Row, 12).Value) And (Cells(Rng.Row, 12).Value <> " ")) Then
                Environment = Cells(Rng.Row, 12).Value
                SetEnv = True
            End If
            If ((IsEmpty(Cells(Rng.Row, 12).Value) Or (Cells(Rng.Row, 12).Value = " ")) And SetEnv = True) Then
                Cells(Rng.Row, 12).Value = Environment
            End If
            If (bToDelete = True And curLevel > iUserSetLevel) Then
                Rows(rowCount).EntireRow.Delete 'Not getting into here...I am stuck here?
            End If
            If (curLevel <= iUserSetLevel) Then
                bToDelete = False
                iUserSetLevel = 0
            End If
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            iPriorLevel = curLevel ' Have to remember prior level in order to continue stripping all lower levels as well
        Next 'Rng
Next 'field
End Sub


Make sure the condition bToDelete = True And curLevel > iUserSetLevel is met debugging with F8 or stop. That way you can see in execution mode what is the exact value of each variable (hover the mouse over each variable and wait a couple of seconds) and see why it's failing.

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I have went into debugging mode a put a watch on bToDelete, curLevel, and iUserSetLevel as I iterate through the loop bToDelete gets set to "False" before getting to curLevel > iUserSetLevel. if that make sense... I am not sure how to stop that to meet condition I want.

The only place where bToDelete gets set to True also has iUserSetLevel = curLevel which means it's never possible for both of these to be true at the same time: bToDelete = True And curLevel > iUserSetLevel (because curLevel will always equal iUserSetLevel due to previous statement). That's why it always skips the delete section.
